# how to find lastlog details in solaris

Tags: linux, authentication, solaris

please advise the equivalent command of linux lastlog in solaris, need to write a script to find the the users last login date and time in solaris servers. Linux its very easy to fetch using lastlog command.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

`last [ -n number] [name]` for last *n* logins or just `last [name]` for all

Comment: I tried last -1 USERID , if any user not logged in that server then there is no ouptut , the task is to find the users who not logged in server more that 90 days, a script should give the output as ServerName USERID 10-Jun-2018  3Days